# Need application like dropdown menu bar like google docs

Tags: javascript, css, menu, menubar

I need a dropdown menu bar like the one used in google docs.

For example here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/18W9-fKs55wiFNjXL9q50PYOnR7-nnsImzJqHOPPbM4E/edit?pli=1

The top menu is File, Edit, View, Help.

I basically want exactly the same menu to be able to use in my application in CSS, Javascript is ok too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many JS/CSS type of menus systems.
Just look on the we or use links provided here.
They are all quite simple to customize

have fun.

http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of google searching I found this http://www.jqueryload.com/jquery-dropdown-menu-with-google-style

[image]